# Database design to store lottery information

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am designing a system where I am supposed to store different types of Lottery(results + tickets).
Currently focusing on US Mega Millions and Singapore Pool Toto. They both have a similar format.

Mega Millions: Five different numbers from 1 to 56 and one number from 1 to 46.
Toto:          6 numbers from 1 to 45

I need to come up with an elegant database design to store the user tickets and corresponding results.
I thought of two ways to go about it.

1. Just store 6 six numbers in 6 columns. 
   OR
2. Create another table(many to many) which has ball-number and ticket_id

I need to store the ball-numbers for the results as well.

For TOTO if you your numbers match 4 or more winning numbers, you win a prize.
For Mega millions there is a similar process.

I'm looking for the pros and cons or possibly a better solution?
I have done a lot of research and paper work, but I am still confused which way to go about it.

Comment: How many records will you be storing?  Are you expecting a large dataset, many weeks worth of user entries, etc.?

Comment: Last 3 years results for each lottery. The users can add tickets. So yes, the data will grow over time(but definitely not at a really large scale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a once a day thing, I think I'd store the data in an easy to edit, maintain, visualize way.  Your many-many approach would work.  Mainly, I'd want it easy to find users that chose a particular ball_number.

```
users
  id
  name

drawings
  id
  type # Mega Millions or Singapore (maybe subclass Drawing) 
  drawing_on

wining_picks
  drawing_id
  ball_number

ticket
  drawing_id
  user_id
  correct_count

picks  
  id
  ticket_id
  ball_number
```

Once you get the numbers in, find all user_ids that pick a particular number in a drawing

Get the drawing by date

```
drawing = Drawing.find_by_drawing_on(drawing_date)
```

Get the users by ball_number and drawing.

```
picked_1 = User.picked(1,drawing)
picked_2 = User.picked(2,drawing)
picked_3 = User.picked(3,drawing)
```

This is a scope on User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.picked(ball_number, drawing)
    joins(:tickets => :picks).where(:picks => {:ball_number => ball_number}, :tickets => {:drawing_id => drawing.id})
  end

end
```

Then do quick array intersections to get the user_ids that got 3,4,5,6 picks correct.  You'd loop through the winning numbers to get the permutations.

For example if the winning numbers were 3,8,21,24,27,44

```
some_3_correct_winner_ids = picked_3 & picked_8 & picked_21  # Array intersection
```

For each winner - update the ticket with correct count.

I may potentially store winners separately, but with an index on correct_count, and not too much data in tickets, this would probably be ok for now.

Comment: I like your approach, although you did not mention how to store the winning numbers(the same way?)

Comment: Good point.  I added a winning picks table.  You could potentially reuse picks, but it's probably better to separate this.  It'll be easier to see and keep safe.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense and I was inclined to go this way from the start :)

Answer (score 2):

**Two tables**

```
tickets
    ball_number
    ticket_id

player
    player_id
    ticket_id

// optional
results
    ball_number
    lottery_id
```

With two tables you could use a query like:

```
select ticket_id, count(ball_number) hits
from tickets 
where ball_number in (wn1, wn2, ...) // wn - winning number
group by ticket_id
having hits = x
```

Of course you could take winning numbers from lottery results table (or store them in the balls_table under special ticket numbers).

Also preparing statistics would be easier. With

```
select count(ticket_id)
from tickets 
group by ball_number
```

you could easily see which numbers are mostly picked.

You might also use some field like lottery number to be able to narrow down the queries as most of them would concern just one lottery.

**One table**

Using one table with a column for each number might make the queries much more complex. Especially that, as I believe, the numbers are sorted, and there are be prizes for hitting all but one (or two) numbers. Than you might have to compare `1, 2, 3, ...` with `2, 3, 4, ...` which is not as short as straightforward as the queries above.

**One column**

Storing all entries in a string in just one column violates all normalization practices, forces you to split the column for most of the queries and takes away all optimization carried out by the database. Also storing numbers requires less disk space than storing text.

Comment: can you detail the schema?
plus in your query what do you mean by ticket_number?

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant lottery_id. I've just fixed it in the answer and added the schema. As you have two types of lotteries, you could either separete them either by introducing two sets of tables or by additional column `lottery_type`. In the schema and code I'm assuming here separate tables solution.

Comment: I've accepted Swards' answer. I don't know why you would put ticket_id in player table.

Comment: To be able to find ticket's owner

Comment: Don't you think it makes more sense to store player_id in tickets table?

Comment: Actually no, as it creates data redundancy. You could have player_details table with information about each player, tickets table to store chosen balls and players table to bind all this together without having to store player details six times for every ticket they bought.

Answer (score 0):

I would just concatenate them using a convention and store them in one column.

Something like '10~20~30~40~50~!60'
~ separates numbers
! indicates special number ( powerball, etc)

Have a sql table valued function split the result if you really need to have it in columns.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because this makes it hard/slow to query your table. If you *do* think it's a good idea, could add the reason why you think so? Please add the pros and cons of "just concatenating"?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me say that I'm an Oracle person, not a MySQL person.

Secondly, I'd usually say to go for a normalised design, but I'm tempted here to think of a very unconventional alternative which I'll float out here for comment.

How about you denormalised it to the extent of using one column for all the number choices?

```
ticket_id      integer
nums           bit(56)
special_number integer
```

It would be a pretty compact representation, and you could perhaps use bit-wise operations to find the winners or potential winners.

No idea if this is workable ... open for comments.

Comment: This question is more or less focused on design rather than a particular dbms. If I use one column to store all numbers, I wouldn't be able to make simplest of queries like get a group by and count etc.